# Copying dynamic rows from one worksheet to another in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a number of rows from each worksheet to the worksheet called "renew" in the same workbook.

The rows are defined as between the key words of `"Service Requests"` and `"Renewals"`.

so step 1: define those row numbers, and step 2: copy them to the Renew sheet.

I run into the problem with step 2, somehow, i couldn't work out how to use the rownumber1 and rownumber2 in the copy command.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Renew").Activate

For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Renew" Then

            For i = 1 To 100

                Dim rownumber1 As Integer
                Dim rownumber2 As Integer

                    If Range("A" & i).Text = "Service Requests" Then
                       rownumber1 = i
                    ElseIf Range("A" & i).Text = "Renewals" Then
                       rownumber2 = i
                    End If

            Next i

       'copy rows between rownumber1 and rownumber2 to the renew sheet

        ws.Rows("rownumber1:rownumber2").EntireRow.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

     End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

update:

```
Sub test2()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim rownumber1 As Integer
Dim rownumber2 As Integer
Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Renew").Activate

For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Renew" Then

            Set FoundCell = ws.Range("A:A").Find(what:="Service Requests", lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            rownumber1 = FoundCell.Row
            End If

            Set FoundCell = ws.Range("A:A").Find(what:="Renewals", lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            rownumber2 = FoundCell.Row
            End If                              

'copy renewals to the renewalsummary

        ws.Rows(rownumber1 & ":" & rownumber2).EntireRow.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

     End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
ws.Rows(rownumber1 & ":" & rownumber2).EntireRow.Copy
```

Although, there are some other things to consider with your code.  It may be a work in progress so I only answered your question, but:

- Your loop is going to return row 100 every time, so I'm curious what the point of your loop is.
- You should never DIM in a loop, since you can only declare a variable once and the loop will attempt to do it every time and *should* throw an error (Dim your rownumber variables with your `ws` variable).
- Why loop to 100?  You should loop to the end of the list of values.

**Reply to Edits**

It looks pretty good.  the main thing is that it works.  Although I would change this:

```
ActiveSheet.Paste Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

to this:

```
ActiveSheet.Paste Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

Hard-coded values aren't very future-proof, this looks at the last row of the sheet (whatever that might be).  If any of your sheets start to reach the row max you need to do this:

```
If Cells(Rows.Count, 1) <> "" Then
  ActiveSheet.Paste Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Else
  MsgBox("Sheet " & ws.Name & " is full, row cannot be copied")
End If
```

But that's probably way down the road and at that point you might be outgrowing Excel.

Comment: Thank you so much. You definitely answered by original question. Thank you also for pointing out these other points, i think they answered some other problems i have. for point 1, what i am trying to do is to return the rownumber for every worksheet. It did work well for a single worksheet, but once i loop through all the sheets, it starts to give weird numbers. And i still do not know why.  For point2, i correct that in the code, thanks for the tips. For point3, as i know there are less than 100 rows, so i used it for a quick code. Can you please elaborate on the point1? Thanks!

Comment: i see what you mean by point 1. And updated by code--it seems to be working, pls let me know if you see any issues or there is a better way of doing it.